# Pygame How To Use Collision?

Tags: python, collision-detection, pygame

Can someone tell me how to implement collision in Pygame?
For example I have a sprite called A and another one called B.
How do I detect if they collide in Pygame?

Comment: Technically, this has very little to do with pygame. It's more a generic algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect

And the several methods following it. You can test against a rectangle, circle, mask, sprite, or group of sprites.

You probably want

```
pygame.sprite.collide_mask(SpriteLeft, SpriteRight): return bool
```

Which checks if two sprites collide based on their bitmasks.

Comment: MmHm, Okay, So Do I Have To Like, Assign Something To The Sprite ?

Comment: You call `is_a_collision = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(A, B)`, and if there was a collision, you `is_a_collision` will be `True`, if there wasn't a collision, `is_a_collision` will be `False`. Please remember to accept an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

I use collisions based on rectangles. Both sprites need a .rect assigned to them.

Then check for a collision

- pygame.sprite.collide_rect(A, B)

  (returns a boolean if there is a collision)

Alternatively you can use the rectangle to check for a collision, eg

- A.rect.colliderect(B.rect)

  (returns a boolean if there is a collision)

I use rect collisions because they're faster than bitmap checks.

Pygame rect docs http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html